# Multiple actions on uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, forms, http-post

In my website, user have to upload a file, and should have two buttons that redirects to either "action1.php" or "action2.php" based on the submit button user clicked.

```
<form action="action1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
    <b>Upload a file:<br/>
          <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="31457"/>
      <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="30" />
     <input type="submit" value="GET SEQUENCE" />

</form>

<form action="action2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
          <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3145728"/>
      <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="30" />
<input type="submit" value="GET HELIX INFO" />
```

Here I have two browse buttons and two actions but the uploaded file is same in both cases. So I want only one browse button and based on what user clicks, it should give either "action1.php" result or "action2.php" result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>

function setAction(form,val,action)
{


form.MAX_FILE_SIZE.value=val;
form.setAttribute('action',action)
form.submit();

}


</script>



<form action="action1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
    <b>Upload a file:<br/>
          <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="31457"/>
      <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile" size="30" />
     <input type="button" value="GET SEQUENCE"  onclick="setAction(this.form,31457,'action1.php')"/>
      <input type="button" value="GET HELIX INFO"  onclick="setAction(this.form,3145728,'action2.php')"/>


</form>
```

Comment: but this is directing both the buttons to "action1.php" in first line of form.

Comment: check my answer ,i have edit it. now it is working and i have solve the bugs and test it on my side.it is working now.apply single quotes in action1.php and action2.php while passing as arguments

Comment: Still both buttons redirects to action1.php

Comment: sorry but the same code is working on my end try to alert the action variable in the function then because it is working on all browsers on my end or could you post the full code which are using

Answer (score 0):

Make a radiobutton named radio and an actions.php file.

Now do this in the actions.php:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_GET["radio"])){
  switch($_GET["radio"]){
  case "a":
    include("action1.php");
    break;
  case "b":
    include("action2.php");
    break;
  default:
    echo "Not valid radio button value";
  }
}
else echo "Not valid radio button value";
?>
```

Comment: Dammed. I wrote the same answer but my browser lagged :-D